# How do I precisely measure sound output duration?

Tags: python, audio, precision, duration, measurement

I'd like to be able to measure the length of time that audio is being played on my system at various locations (sometimes it's not possible to tie a file to the audio event).  There's no locked file type, so I'd just like to be able to figure out the sound event and map its duration.  I'm trying to output the duration info into a log file or a console, you know?

I'm not really sure where to start looking, but I feel like Python is the right language for the job.  I've been able to get pixel colors and read CAPTCHA and such, so I figure it should be able to do this as well.  I wonder if I will need to know more VB, though, because I'm on a Windows system?